# OAuth - Access Token expiration period?

Tags: oauth, twitter

Does anyone know what the expiration period of an OAuth Access Token is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That depends on the provider, but in most cases it's valid until the account holder revokes your access.

Twitter for example - it doesn't expire, but the user can revoke your access.

Comment: but it can be revoked when it expired right?

Answer (score 24):

This depends on the organization policy for the Oauth implementation. Typically the lifetime of the token last from several hours to couples of weeks [oauth2 Documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/). What can be derived from the Amazon [Amazon: Access Tokens](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/access-token.html), Facebook [Facebook:Expiration and Extension of Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), Salesforce [salforce forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009CYiIAM), and google documentation is the lifetime of access is usually within 24 hours, typically, 1 hour to 2 hours. The refresh token stay alive for longer period which is used to invalidate the access token. furthermore, A short survey of the desired  category application would be helpful. For example, I am currently working on eCommerce app, so, I am going to find out how long is the lifetime of the access token in the other application of the same category like Amazon and wallmart.

**Update:**

eCommerce applications and payment gateways has the access token lifetime within 10 hours. while, Social media applications has access token lifetime up to six months.

[image]